# Hadoop3 balancer vs disk balancer

Tags: hadoop3

I read Hadoop ver 3 [document about disk balancer](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSDiskbalancer.html) and it said

"Diskbalancer is a command line tool that distributes data evenly on all disks of a datanode.
This tool is different from [Balancer](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html#Balancer) which takes care of cluster-wide data balancing."

I really dont know whats difference between 'balancer' and 'disk balancer' yet.
Could you explain what is it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Balancer deals with internodes data balancing present in multiple datanodes present in the cluster whereas disk balancer deals with data present disks of a single datanode.

Comment: Thank you for your good answer! Now i can tell what they are!